# How to see a Google map in 3D mode?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an Android/iOS app with React Native and I want to show street in 3D mode, the
same as screenshot 2.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the map method : animateToViewingAngle(angle). https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Answer (score 0):

Native google map for iOS (objective-C), android (Java), and airbnb map, too, they have "3D-map" feature by default, of course!

Besides, it actually depends on the zoom-level that you will see the buildings in 3D (but you also need to make the map "inclined" - by using 2 fingers and move forward/backward to see the sides of the buildings ^^)

Comment: No i need to do this automatic wihtout fingers when user click on marker

Comment: Then, you can set the default zoom level, perhaps 15 or 16, and may also set the "inclined" degree of the map (which is TILT) on its first display ^^ I believe you will find your own way setting the necessary parameters for your map, thanks